# Insert special characters in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, string

I tried looking for a solution but could not find one...

I have a string of characters wich contains a lot of single and double qoutes. So i changed that string with the correct notations.

When i echo that variable part of it looks like this...

```
{"mosaic_item_title":"-none-","mosaic_item_description":"
```

etc.... But when i look in the database it has written this value.

```
{&quot;mosaic_item_title&quot;:&quot;-none-&quot;,&quot [...]
```

So i had to change it to this else i could not set it in a variable but now i have to change it back somehow?

The line below does not work. It still writes the &quot rules to the database.

```
$insert_rok_string = mysql_real_escape_string($rok_string);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try serializing the data before you insert it

Comment: Some of your other code converts some characters into entity codes. It's your code, not some php magic.

Comment: How did you `change that string with the correct annotations`? Just because it looks correct in a browser doesn't mean that it doesn't contain `&quot;` because a browser __will__ display that as `"`

Comment: &quot; renders in html as a double quote, so when you echo, it will look like a double quote in your browser.  Make sure you use View Source to look at that variable.

Comment: Look for a call to `htmlspecialchars` somewhere in your code, that is what does this. You don't need to use `htmlspecialchars` when saving data to database, only when the data is output in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using the escape \ when setting the variables.

So simple....